# How can you pass the model to the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I've just started looking at [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) after watching the [MIX 11](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08) talk and it looks very promising.

I can understand how to pass your model back to your controller as json and update/save the model, but how can I pass my model to my view and make it observable?

For example if I have the following class:

```
public class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I can pass it from my controller as json using a JsonResult so I send something like to my view:

```
{ 
    firstName : "Bob",
    lastName : "Jones"
};
```

Now, how do I make the properties observable and make this a viewModel within my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
url: 'Home/GetUserData',
type: 'post',
success: function (data) {
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
viewModel.save = function () { sendToServer(); };
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
});
```

You will also need to use the mapping plugin.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Notice the ko.mapping.fromJS(data); which is taking the model from the mvc endpoint and prepping it for observable.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an article that helped me: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332406/Client-side-Model-binding-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-K

It shows a way to bind viewmodel without ajax calls and without doing additional conversions at controller side.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using the ko.mapping plugin. I think the mapping plugin works two-way (which is not your case).

I have declared an Html Helper >

```
public static string ToJson(this object obj)
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(obj);


        }
```

which serializes my server-side module to the client size JSON and declare it at the client end.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer uses JQuery. This works perfectly well but isn't required. See:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/